# How to validate file name from textbox on button click? VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, validation, textbox

I would like to know how to check if the file name that is inserted from textbox exist in the same folder as the program itself.

For example, I'm going to enter notepad.exe into textbox then when you click the button it will check if that program exist on the folder where the program is. If I enter notepad.ex into textbox then it didn't find any file with that name, then it will give error.

Answer (score 2):

Simply append a **".\"** at the start of the filename, this will check on the current directory path, which always will be the same directory on which your main assembly is:

```
Dim filename As String = TextBox1.Text

If Not File.Exists(String.Format(".\{0}", filename)) Then
    MessageBox.Show("File not found.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

Else
    ' File found.

End If
```

I suggest to use `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` only when you are not sure what the working directory is, for example when changed the default working directory path with `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory()` method.

Comment: I'm using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() because the program I'm making isn't always at the same folder or path every time. But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use this code to check if the file exist or not.

```
Dim currentPath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), Textbox1.Text)

    If IO.File.Exists(currentPath) Then
        ..Do something here
    Else
        MsgBox("Executable doesn't exist!", vbOKOnly, "Error!")
    End If
```

Comment: Do not post question part as answer. Edit your question